# .NET Regex to Match any word

Tags: .net, regex

I try to match a string in this format:

```
Fixed sentence http://t.co/variable_part fixed_word @fixed_word
```

the only unknown part in this string is variable_part, the rest is fixed. So I use:

```
Fixed sentence http://t.co/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) fixed_word @fixed_word
```

as the match pattern. Altough it works well in some online parsers, not in some .NET based online parsers (like http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) and in my .NET code. What am I missing?

Comment: I really dont understand much, what you are trying to get but is this not helped ?

http://t.co/([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)

Comment: Just a little software tip: Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). A little tool to build and test regex. There you can also change the programming language with wich you want to use the regex string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the underscore in the character class

```
@"Fixed sentence http://t.co/([\w-]+) fixed_word @fixed_word"
```

I changed the class and used `\w` thats including letters, digits and the underscore (in .net letters and digits are of course unicode letters and digits, not only ASCII, but since you want to match any word ...)

Comment: I'd probably use `\S` or `[^\s/]` in that case, and he didn't say he was using C#. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the underscore to the character class. Also you want to escape the `.`:

```
Fixed sentence http://t\.co/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) fixed_word @fixed_word
```

Answer (score 0):

single comments doesnt allow the adding code I think so I shared the code here

```
http://t.co/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to 'escape' the non alpha characters.. so something like..

```
Fixed sentence http\:\/\/t\.co\/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+) fixed\_word \@fixed\_word
```

Definitely for the period (.) that is a special character.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to escape only those characters, that have a special meaning in regex, this is in this regex for .net only the dot. all others will be matched literally.

Comment: I agree, but I tend to escape all punctuation, as a lot of it is 'special' and I'd rather be safe.